# Write Pid of a deamon in a file

Tags: c, printf, pid

This is my code and I'm trying to write a pid in a file, I'm using fprintf but it doesn't work
This is my code :

```
int write_pid_in_file(struct config *conf, pid_t pid)
{
    //conf->global->pid_file = /tmp/HTTPd.pid
    FILE *file_opened = fopen(conf->global->pid_file,"w+");
    if (!file_opened)
        return 2;
    printf("%d\n",pid); //check if it's the good pid
    fprintf(file_opened, "%d\n",pid);
    fclose(file_opened);
    return 0;
}
```

In this function I call the write function and I get the pid from the demone

```
int daemon_start(struct config *conf)
{
    pid_t cpid;

    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(0);
    }

    write_pid_in_file(conf,cpid);

    if (cpid > 0)
    {
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);
        exit(0);
    }
   
    serv(conf->vhosts); //infinite loop 

    return 0;
}

I'm doing this bc later I need to make a function who stop this deamon   ^^
```

Comment: That indicates your function is called twice.

Comment: Add `printf("Writing to \"%s\"\n", conf->global->pid_file);` right after the `fprintf` and see what happens and tell us about it.

Comment: please make a [mre] that has a main and just calls this function.

Comment: Then you have another place where you write to the same file. Your code only writes one line. Where does the first number come from?

Comment: No, calling that function 2 times would also add the extra print 2 times. BTW: Why did you delete the comment with that information?

Comment: It is rather annoying if you delete your comments all the time.

Comment: I'm just trying to make it more understandable; soory ..

Comment: How doesn't it work?

Comment: This is the output :  `6944 \n 0\n` I d'ont know why there is a 0 and when I cat the file :  `0 \n 44\n` and actually 6944 is the good PID

Comment: Is that the output you see on stdout, or in the file?  I would expect you to see `6944\n0\n` on stdout, and only one of those  values in the file, and which one you see is non-deterministic.

Comment: If you don't want to see `0` in the pid file, don't let the child write to it.  Having both the parent and child racing to write to the file is bound to corrupt the data.

Comment: Okey it works I call this function when  `cpid > 0`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Given the code

```
int daemon_start(struct config *conf)
{
    pid_t cpid;

    cpid = fork();

    if (cpid == -1)
    {
        perror("fork");
        exit(0);
    }

    write_pid_in_file(conf,cpid);  <-- both parent and child will call this
       .
       .
       .
```

There will be **two** processes that call `write_pid_in_file()` - the **parent** process will write the pid of the **child** process, and the **child** process will write `0`.